# JSON created_time conversion preg_replace $string input

Tags: php, facebook, json, graph, preg-replace

This is a hard one to described. So I'm using the Facebook graph to display a view of my pages facebook/twitter (via Facebook) on a website. Everything is great except that I'm trying to get the created_time into a better format. I've tested the pout of of created_time to make sure it works, like so....

```
$string = 2012-02-06T19:38:35+0000
```

However, when I try to dynamically pass the $data->created_time; it doesn't like what it gets, so it says that the date is Jan 01 1970. I know it's probably getting something unreadable back, but I can't see what it is in order to diagnose it. :/

Here's all of the code...

```
<?php 

$info = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/210849652406/feed/?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]&limit=20'));

$string =  $info->data->created_time;
$pattern = '/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\+(\d{4})/i';
$replacement = '$3-$2-$1 $4:$5:$6';
$new_time = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);


 $dTime = strtotime($new_time);
 //format the date / time into something human readable
 //if you want it formatted differently look up the php date function
 $myTime=date("M d Y h:ia",$dTime);


if ($info) {

foreach ($info->data as $obj) {
    if ($obj->application->name =='Twitter') {
    echo "<div class=\"ca-item\"><div class=\"ca-item-main-twitter\">";
    echo "<div><span class=\time\><a href=\"https://twitter.com/#!/ouhsd\">@OUHSD--", $myTime,"</a></span>";
    echo "<span class=\"content\">", $obj->message, "</span></div>" ;
    echo "<div class=\"us\"></div>";
    echo "</div></div>";
    }
}   
}
?>
```

Comment: If `$string` is `2012-02-06T19:38:35+0000`, can't you just skip the regex and do `strtotime($string)`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I had some unnecsesary preg_replace-ing going on because I thought that the timestamp was too complicated for strtotime but I was calling the created_time before the foreach so it wasn't really valid. I knew I should have gone to lunch sooner!

Answer (score 0):

TIP: Don't postpone lunch when you starving in order to troubleshoot something. Odds are you'll solve it after lunch when you're not starving and less desperate to solve the problem. The answer was more simple than I thought!

The solution...

```
<?php 

$info = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/210849652406/feed/?access_token=305397012843053|0Lge1zfZW1kE77tnJ0gbmcGLNuo&limit=20'));

if ($info) {

foreach ($info->data as $obj) {

 $dTime = strtotime($obj->created_time);
 //format the date / time into something human readable
 //if you want it formatted differently look up the php date function
 $myTime=date("M d Y h:ia",$dTime);
        if ($obj->application->name =='Twitter') {

    echo "<div class=\"ca-item\"><div class=\"ca-item-main-twitter\">";
    echo "<div><span class=\time\><a href=\"https://twitter.com/#!/ouhsd\">@OUHSD--", $myTime,"</a></span>";
    echo "<span class=\"content\">", $obj->message, "</span></div>" ;
    echo "<div class=\"us\"></div>";
    echo "</div></div>";
    }
}   
}
?>
```

I was trying to fix the time before it was called, and I had unnecessary